# How to Color TableViewer Rows alternatively

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I'm using Viewer Framework in my rcp application, i would like to color viewer rows alternatively,i tried to override getBackground method of ColumnLabelProvider, below is code snippet

```
col.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider(){
  ----//other methods 
  @override
  public Color getBackground(Object element) {
  return gray;//here gray is color object defined somewhere in class
  }
 });
```

this colors the columns, but not a row, below is output

[image]

how do i achieve this correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find an example [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-eclipse-rcp1/section7.html) which uses an [`IColorProvider`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/IColorProvider.html). Maybe you could just reuse the `getBackground()` method in your code, just change the reference to your `tableViewer`:

```
public Color getBackground(Object element) {
    ArrayList list = (ArrayList) tableViewer.getInput();
    int index = list.indexOf(element);
    if ((index % 2) == 0) {
        return gray;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Has anyone figured out, how to set the IColorProvider for the tableviewer?

Comment: Use `tableViewer.setLabelProvider(provider)`. The `provider` can implement then optional interface `IColorProvider`.